# Zoom on a div text and display it on a block (onClick and using Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm tryin to use this code (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp
) to display and make a zoom on a div that contains a text  (instead of the image) after clicking on it, but that doesn't work.

I want to have the same effect when I click on my div which contains text, but i think that this code is only valid for images?

I tried this :

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Trigger the Modal -->
<div id="myImg">
    <p>Hello world</p>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close">&times;</span>

  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption {
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)}
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var div = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
div.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "table-row";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend spending time reviewing CSS (and JavaScript) though specifically going through all the things you can now do with CSS.

```
.zoom:active {transform: scale(2, 2.5);}
```

[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) has the best documentation.